# self executing function assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have found an example to run a server using Express but I don't understand 'why' it works.

The code is the following:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

The result of this var assignment is a process listening at port 3000, but I am assigning something not executing.

What am I missing?

Cheers, Giovanni

Comment: you are assigning the result of `app.listen()` to your server variable, `app.listen()` is being executed.

Comment: In what sense is that "self executing"?

Comment: you are executing the app.listen command which does it's majicks and returns the server instance (I guess) that you use for doing other things with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript `app.listen()` is a method call that executes the `listen()` method on the `app` object.  The return value from that method call is then assigned to your `server` variable.

So, putting it all together with your code:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

The sequence of events is this:

1. Declare a new variable named `server` in the current scope.
2. Call the `listen()` method on the `app` object with `app.listen(...)`.
3. Pass that method two arguments, `3000` as the port number and a callback function that will be called when the `.listen()` method finishes.
4. Whatever value the `app.listen()` method returns is then assigned to the `server` variable.

> The result of this var assignment is a process listening at port 3000,
>   but I am assigning something not executing.

Actually, you're doing both.  You're calling the `app.listen()` method and then assigning the return result to the `server` variable.

The phrase `self executing` doesn't really apply here.  The parens after `app.listen()` make this a function call which will execute the `.listen()` method on the `app` object.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was confused by the listen() function and the anonymous function (callback) within listen(). It makes totally sense now.

Answer (score 0):

`app.listen` is a method that accepts arguments and returns some object.  Something like this

```
app.listen  = function(time, handlerFunc) {
    // do some stuff
    return someObject;
}
```

Comment: this code overwrites `app.listen` method - surely not what is required

Comment: @JaromandaX I was providing a pseudo-code example of how app.listen might be defined-- that's all-- op wondering why the definition works from that method-- this is an example. His question doesn't ask how to _do_ anything.